# Php and Mysql do not send query to the server

Tags: php, mysql

I developed web form and connected to mysql db. When I tested on local hosting (on my computer) it worked ok, all INSERT queries were done successfully, but when I uploaded on hosting (tried on 2 hosting companies) all Inserts in db are empty.

What problem can be?

My code

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'cy57447_forms', '123456789', 'cy57447_forms');

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $tg_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tg_username']);
    $bitcointalk_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bitcointalk_username']);
    $bitcointalk_profile_link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bitcointalk_profile_link']);
    $twitter_account_url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['twitter_account_url']);
    $number_of_followers = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number_of_followers']);
    $twitter_audit_link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['twitter_audit_link']);
    $ethereum_wallet = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ethereum_wallet']);
    $tokens = '';
}

    $sql = "INSERT INTO twitter_form (`tg_username`, `bitcointalk_username`, `bitcointalk_profile_link`, `twitter_account_url`, `number_of_followers`, `twitter_audit_link`, `ethereum_wallet`, `email`, `tokens`) VALUES ('$tg_username', '$bitcointalk_username', '$bitcointalk_profile_link', '$twitter_account_url', '$number_of_followers', '$twitter_audit_link', '$ethereum_wallet','$email', '');";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

Comment: Encountered any SQL connection error? Some hosting company may not host DB together with the server, hence "localhost" as the host address may not work.

Comment: It would probably help if you would also include a snippet of the HTML page that contains the form which submits data to the PHP page. This could also be the source of the problem.

Comment: Preferably change to using prepared statements in mysqli_, but 
 changing to `mysqli_real_escape_string` may work.

Comment: are you sure you've configured mysql with your hosting running on default port 80

Comment: Isn't connection to database, 3306? port 80 is for http connection.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **host**, **username**, **password**, and **database** names are all correct?

To help your debugging process I would suggest using a try catch around your connection attempt

```
    try{
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'cy57447_forms', '123456789', 'cy57447_forms');
         //if condition
         $sql = "INSERT INTO twitter_form
                    ( ` tg_username ` ,
                     ` bitcointalk_username ` ,
                     ` bitcointalk_profile_link ` ,
                     ` twitter_account_url ` ,
                     ` number_of_followers ` ,
                     ` twitter_audit_link ` ,
                     ` ethereum_wallet ` ,
                     ` email ` ,
                     ` tokens ` )
        VALUES      ('$tg_username',
                     '$bitcointalk_username',
                     '$bitcointalk_profile_link',
                     '$twitter_account_url',
                     '$number_of_followers',
                     '$twitter_audit_link',
                     '$ethereum_wallet',
                     '$email',
                     '');";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = [
            'error' => $e->getCode(),
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
            'traceString' => $e->getTraceAsString()
        ];
        var_dump($error);
    }
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

Comment: This is more a debugging aid rather than a solution to the problem.  Also not sure if adding extra spaces around the column names in the backticks will work.

Comment: Not adding extra spaces on Query I have just used sql formatter to format the query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you to check this line.

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'cy57447_forms', '123456789', 'cy57447_forms');
```

Codes look fine to me.

1. If the database on the hosting company local or there is another endpoint/url to connect to for database. It's not all the time localhost on the hosting server.
2. The username and password to the database. If you go through some wizard on Cpanel etc, use those password and username.
3. The name of the database, make sure there is no prefix etc.

Thanks to @Nigel Ran in the comments. 
You may also want to try to change

```
mysql_real_escape_string
```

to

```
mysqli_real_escape_string
```

Comment: *Codes look fine to me* - Do you think that `mysql_real_escape_string()` should be used with `mysqli_connect()`?

Comment: You are right. I missed it.

Comment: @Nigel Ren, why not you post the answer? I think you may be right about that. The mixed use of mysql and mysqli PHP functions.

Comment: I have not posted an answer as I've voted to close the question as a duplicate.